# A functional binary heap implementation

Tags: optimization, f#, heap

I've implemented a binary heap in F#. It's pure and uses zippers for tree modification.
To test it out I have implemented heap sort using it but it takes 10 seconds to sort a list of 100 000. Regular List.sort is instant and since heap sort should have the same complexity I'm wondering what I can do to improve my implementation.

Profiling revealed most of the time (above 50%) is spent in the bubble down, which is to be expected since sort is basically just don't a bunch of removes but nothing in the method is really exceptionally slow (that I can see).

```
#nowarn "25"

namespace FSharpExt

module Heap =
    type HeapNode<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison> = 
        | Full of 'a * 'b * HeapNode<'a, 'b> * HeapNode<'a, 'b>
        | Half of 'a * 'b * HeapNode<'a, 'b>
        | Leaf of 'a * 'b
        | Empty

    let (|KeyValue|) zipper =
        match zipper with
        | Full(k, v, _, _) | Half(k, v, _) | Leaf(k, v) -> (k, v)
        | Empty -> failwith "List is empty"

    let cut node =
        match node with
        | Leaf(k, v)          -> Empty
        | Half(k, v, _)       -> Leaf(k, v)
        | Full(k, v, left, _) -> Half(k, v, left)

    type Direction = Left | Right
    type Pointer = Direction list

    let rec next pointer =
        match pointer with
        | []                    -> [Left]
        | x :: xs when x = Left -> Right :: xs
        | x :: xs               -> Left :: next xs

    let rec previous pointer =
        match pointer with
        | [Left]                 -> []
        | x :: xs when x = Right -> Left :: xs
        | x :: xs                -> Right :: previous xs

    type Zipper<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison> = Zipper of HeapNode<'a, 'b> * (HeapNode<'a, 'b> * Direction) list 

    let moveLeftZipper (Zipper((Full(_, _, left, _) | Half(_, _, left)) as node, path)) = Zipper(left, (node, Left) :: path)

    let moveRightZipper (Zipper(Full(_, _, _, right) as node, path)) = Zipper(right, (node, Right) :: path)

    let moveDirectionZipper direction zipper =
        match direction with
        | Left  -> moveLeftZipper zipper
        | Right -> moveRightZipper zipper

    let moveAlongPathZipper path zipper = List.fold (Func.flip moveDirectionZipper) zipper (List.rev path)

    let moveUpZipper (Zipper(current, (last, dir) :: path)) =
        match last, dir with
        | Full(k, v, _, right), Left -> Zipper(Full(k, v, current, right), path)
        | Half(k, v, _), Left        -> Zipper(Half(k, v, current), path)
        | Full(k, v, left, _), Right -> Zipper(Full(k, v, left, current), path)

    let rec toRootZipper (Zipper(current, path) as zipper) =
        match path with
        | []      -> zipper
        | x :: xs -> zipper |> moveUpZipper |> toRootZipper   

    let keyValue (Zipper(KeyValue(k, v), _)) = (k, v)

    let modifyCurrentZipper (k, v) (Zipper(current, path)) =
        match current with
        | Full(_, _, left, right) -> Zipper(Full(k, v, left, right), path)
        | Half(_, _, left)        -> Zipper(Half(k, v, left), path)
        | _                       -> Zipper(Leaf(k, v), path)

    let appendLeafZipper (k, v) (Zipper(current, path)) =
        match current with
        | Half(ck, cv, left) -> Zipper(Full(ck, cv, left, Leaf(k, v)), path) |> moveRightZipper
        | Leaf(ck, cv)       -> Zipper(Half(ck, cv, Leaf(k, v)), path) |> moveLeftZipper
        | Empty              -> Zipper(Leaf(k, v), [])

    let removeLeafZipper zipper =
        match zipper with
        | Zipper(_, (node, dir) :: path) -> Zipper(cut node, path)
        | _                              -> Zipper(Empty, [])

    let rec bubbleUpZipper (Zipper(KeyValue(k, v), path) as zipper) =
        match path with
        | (KeyValue(pk, pv), _) :: rest when pk > k -> modifyCurrentZipper (pk, pv) zipper |> moveUpZipper |> modifyCurrentZipper (k, v) |> bubbleUpZipper
        | _                                         -> zipper 

    let rec bubbleDownZipper (Zipper(current, _) as zipper) =
        let move fn (ak, av) (bk, bv) = modifyCurrentZipper (bk, bv) zipper |> fn |> modifyCurrentZipper (ak, av) |> bubbleDownZipper
        let right = move moveRightZipper
        let left = move moveLeftZipper
        match current with
        | Full(k, v, KeyValue(lk, lv), KeyValue(rk, rv)) when k > lk || k > rk -> if lk > rk then right (k, v) (rk, rv) else left (k, v) (lk, lv)
        | Half(k, v, KeyValue(lk, lv)) when k > lk                             -> left (k, v) (lk, lv)
        | _                                                                    -> zipper

    let toRoot (zipper, pointer) = (toRootZipper zipper, pointer)
    let appendLeaf (k, v) (zipper, pointer) = (moveAlongPathZipper (List.tail pointer) zipper |> appendLeafZipper (k, v), next pointer)
    let removeLeaf (zipper, pointer) = (moveAlongPathZipper (previous pointer) zipper |> removeLeafZipper, previous pointer)
    let bubbleUp (zipper, pointer) = (bubbleUpZipper zipper, pointer)
    let bubbleDown (zipper, pointer) = (bubbleDownZipper zipper, pointer)

    type Heap<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison> = Heap of Zipper<'a, 'b> * Pointer
    let (|Root|) (Heap(Zipper(root, _), _)) = root

    let insert (k, v) (Heap(zipper, pointer)) = appendLeaf (k, v) (zipper, pointer) |> bubbleUp |> toRoot |> Heap
    let min (Heap(zipper, pointer)) = keyValue zipper
    let remove (Heap(zipper, pointer)) = 
        (modifyCurrentZipper (moveAlongPathZipper (previous pointer) zipper |> keyValue) zipper, pointer) 
        |> removeLeaf 
        |> toRoot 
        |> bubbleDown 
        |> toRoot 
        |> Heap
    let pop heap = (min heap, remove heap)
    let tryPop heap =
        match heap with
        | Root(Empty) -> None
        | _           -> pop heap |> Some

    let singleton (k, v) = Heap(Zipper(Leaf(k, v), []), [Left])

    let empty = Heap(Zipper(Empty, []), [])

    let ofList list = 
        match list with
        | []            -> empty
        | first :: tail -> List.fold (fun h x -> insert x h) (singleton first) tail

    let ofValues list fn =
        match list with
        | []            -> empty
        | first :: tail -> List.fold (fun h x -> insert (fn x, x) h) (singleton (fn first, first)) tail

    let sort list = ofValues list id |> Seq.unfold tryPop |> Seq.map snd |> List.ofSeq
```

The source is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/LukaHorvat/f-sharp-ext). Feel free to clone it if you want to profile it or something.

Comment: Hi, your GitHub repo is missing some files (PriorityQueue.fs, PriorityQueue.fsi, Heap.fsi) and won't build.

Comment: @mjolka Thanks for the warning. I fixed it now. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Representing the heap as an array may improve performance considerably by having localised memory access.
E.g.: http://www.cse.hut.fi/en/research/SVG/TRAKLA2/tutorials/heap_tutorial/taulukkona.html

Comment: @Mau Doesn't really go well with the whole pure functional thing.

Comment: @Darwin: totally agree. However the comparison is against an implementation that exploits the locality of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'm not surprised that your algorithm is significantly slower than `List.sort`:

1. `List.sort` is implemented using `Array.Sort`, which uses [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort). Normal (array-based) heapsort is one of the slower sorting algorithms.
2. When compared with normal heapsort, you're using a separate object for each item in the collection.
3. When compared with mutable tree-based heapsort, you're also creating garbage when "mutating" the tree.

All these put together mean that functional heapsort is never going to be anywhere near `List.sort` in terms of performance.

---

I don't see why you're using zippers here at all. After each operation, the zipper is positioned at the root of the tree, so you might as well use just the binary tree (plus a pointer to the next leaf position). All it does is to make your code more complicated (and probably less efficient).

---

```
type HeapNode<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison> =
```

`'a` and `'b` are pretty bad names. All names you use should be meaningful.

---

```
| Full of 'a * 'b * HeapNode<'a, 'b> * HeapNode<'a, 'b>
| Half of 'a * 'b * HeapNode<'a, 'b>
| Leaf of 'a * 'b
| Empty
```

I don't understand why do you have both `Empty` and a special case for inner node with one child empty.

---

```
let (|KeyValue|) zipper =
```

This is very confusing, since `zipper` is not a `Zipper`, it's a `HeapNode`.

---

```
let rec next pointer =
    match pointer with
    | []                    -> [Left]
    | x :: xs when x = Left -> Right :: xs
    | x :: xs               -> Left :: next xs
```

I don't see any reason to use `when` here, you could write this as:

```
let rec next pointer =
    match pointer with
    | []          -> [Left]
    | Left :: xs  -> Right :: xs
    | Right :: xs -> Left :: next xs
```

Or even (if you're okay with not naming the parameter):

```
let rec next =
    function
    | []          -> [Left]
    | Left :: xs  -> Right :: xs
    | Right :: xs -> Left :: next xs
```

---

```
let rec toRootZipper (Zipper(current, path) as zipper) =
    match path with
    | []      -> zipper
    | x :: xs -> zipper |> moveUpZipper |> toRootZipper
```

You don't need to name variables you're not going to use. Here, you could just write `_` instead of `x :: xs`.

---

```
let ofList list = 
    match list with
    | []            -> empty
    | first :: tail -> List.fold (fun h x -> insert x h) (singleton first) tail
```

You could start folding from `empty` instead of `singleton first`. That way, you wouldn't even need a special case for the empty list:

```
let ofList list = List.fold (fun h x -> insert x h) empty list
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to review my code. I'll assimilate the changes :D They all make sense.
Oh, and I didn't know naming generic parameters was a thing. I thought using a, b, c.. was the convention.

Comment: Oh, and let me just add that I'm not using zipper for performance. It's just that the algorithm was easier to express for me when I can use the notion of moving through the tree.

Comment: When you have just a single obvious generic parameter, calling it `'T` or `'a` is fine. But when there's more than one, or when it's not obvious, you should name them.

Comment: And the way you talk about moving, it kind of sounds to me like you're thinking imperatively. I *think* your code would be simpler if you got rid of the zipper (but I could be wrong, I've never actually implemented functional heapsort).